# Lie bracket of a vector field at a point $p \in M$.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

Let $M$ be a manifold and let  $ X , Y $ two vector fields on $M$.  I know ths definition of the  Lie bracket between $X $ and $Y$ $[X,Y]: C^\infty(M)\rightarrow C^\infty(M)$ is an $\mathbb R$-linear map such that $[X,Y]f:=X(Yf)-Y(Xf)$.

However, if $p \in M $ I'm not sure what is the explicit expression of $[X,Y](p)$?

Comment: What is your definition of "explicit expression"? You may try to work out an example, e.g. $M = \Bbb R^2, p = (0, 0)$.

Comment: @WhatsUp, I mean by that what is the value of $[X,Y](p) \in T_pM$ when it's applied to a function? Actually I ask this question when I read in the article " orbites coadjointes et Cohomologie Équivariante", that  if  a vector field $X_M $ on M vanishes at a point $m \in M$ and if  $\xi$ is a vector field on M, defined on a neighborhood of m, then the value of $[X_M, \xi]$ at the point m depends only on the value  $\xi (m)$, so that's why I'm wondering what is $ [X_M, \xi](m)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $(x^1,\ldots,x^n)$ is a local coordinate patch and $\left(\partial_1,\ldots,\partial_n\right)$ are the associated tangent vector fields. Then locally, there exist functions $X^i$ and $Y^j$ such that:
\begin{align}
X &= \sum_{i=1}^nX^i\partial_i, & Y &=\sum_{j=1}^nY^j\partial_j.
\end{align}
If $f$ is a function, then:
\begin{align}
Y\cdot f = \mathrm{d}f(Y) = \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\mathrm{d}x^i\right) Y = \sum_{i=1}^n Y^i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}.
\end{align}
Thus:
\begin{align}
X\cdot(Y\cdot f) &= \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\left(Y\cdot f \right)\mathrm{d}x^j\right)X \\
 &= \sum_{j=1}^nX^j\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n Y^i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \right) \right) \\
&=\sum_{i,j=1}^nX^j \left(\frac{\partial Y^i}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} + Y^i \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^j\partial x^i} \right).
\end{align}
Therefore, it follows that:
\begin{align}
[X,Y]f &= X\cdot(Y\cdot f) - Y\cdot(X \cdot f)\\
&=\sum_{i,j=1}^n X^j\frac{\partial Y^i}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} - Y^j\frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} + X^jY^i\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^j\partial x^i} - Y^jX^i\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^j\partial x^i}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^n X^j\frac{\partial Y^i}{\partial x^j}- Y^j\frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^j} \right) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} + 0 \tag{$\star$}\\
&= \mathrm{d}f \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^n X^j\frac{\partial Y^i}{\partial x^j}- Y^j\frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^j} \right) \partial_i \right),
\end{align}
where ($\star$) is a consequence of Swcharz's lemma, that is $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^j \partial x^i} = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}$. Hence, in local coordinates:
$$
[X,Y] = \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^n X^j \frac{\partial Y^i}{\partial x^j} - Y^j\frac{\partial X ^i}{\partial x^j}\right) \partial_i.
$$
Note that thanks to Schwarz's lemma, it is canonically defined. Otherwise, as the second partial derivative of functions depends on the choosen chart, it would not have been a canonical expression.

To answer your comment: if $X(m)=0$, the above expression shows that
$$
[X,\xi](m) = - \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \xi^j(m)\frac{X^i}{\partial x^j}(m)\right) \partial_i,
$$
which does not depend on the local behaviour of $\xi$ around $m$ but just on its value $\xi(m)$.

Comment: This was really very helpful! thank you so much @Didier for this nice explanation, I really appreciate it .